# Send selected text to dialer

Tags: phone-app

Is there an App that registers itself as a Share Command and lets me send a selected text in a webpage or email to the default dialer?
I would like to avoid copy and pasting a number from a webpage or email to the dialer manually...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the exact same thing and thanks to your question, I just found the answer! There you go!

[**Send To Dialer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=iw&id=com.czero.sendtodialer)

Answer (score 1):

I guess [Clipboard Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.grenangen.clipboarddialer) might be your choice:

> This little tool enables you to extract all phone numbers from what ever text is in your clipboard. It will present a list of all numbers it finds giving you an easy way to call, SMS or create a new contact.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I'm looking for.
Using this tool I have to copy to the clipboard open the app and click dial there. I would like to select the text (phone number) hit the little arrow down button, hit "Share" and select something like "Send to Dialer"...

Comment: Nothing I know of that would do that. And basically it's the same, just using the Share app (yepp, app) instead of the clipboard app.